# Spring Data-Couchbase Client Configuration with moxi Client Possible?

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

We are running client-side MOXI on the same machine as our Tomcat servers, with MOXI currently talking to a cluster of membase servers on 3 different machines.  The java clients talk to MOXI using spymemcached communicating to MOXI through data port 11211.

We are going to migrate to Couchbase now and from a development perspective, we'd like to use spring-data with couchbase but our infrastructure team want to keep MOXI on the client machines and only communicate via port 11211.  It seems that when configuring the Couchbase client, this won't work as MOXI doesn't proxy the port 8901 (admin port) that the CouchbaseClient class uses to discover the Couchbase cluster.  Does this mean that if we keep our current infrastructure that Spring Data is off the table?

I am new to this and have went through the Couchbase documentation, and it seems like what I want to do isn't possible, but would like to confirm this.  Currently, to configure spring-data I am using this:

```
<couchbase:couchbase bucket="appsbucket" password="" host="localhost"/>
<couchbase:repositories base-package="com.pathto.myrepositories"/>
```

Localhost is where MOXI is running, but the assumption made by the the couchbase bean (the CouchbaseClient configuration) is that the couchbase admin port is available at port 8901.  Of course, if instead of localhost I point it toward one of the servers hosting Couchbase, I don't have an issue other than our infrastructure team takes umbrage with this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you move to Couchbase with a smart client there isn't really much value in moxi; and in fact you'll be introducing an additional network hop (client -> moxi; moxi -> cluster).

You can think of the smart clients as conceptually having an *embedded moxi* - as the smart clients are aware of the cluster topology and know which node to communicate with to access a given document.

I suggest you take a look a the [Deployment strategies](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-deployment-strategies.html) section in the Couchbase admin guide which explains all this in more detail.